# UpdateLayeredWindow failed in windows 7 GetLastError 87

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, gdi+

Window Create Code:

```cpp
LPCTSTR lpszClassName = AfxRegisterWndClass(CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW, AfxGetApp()->LoadStandardCursor(IDC_ARROW),
    (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(TRANSPARENT), NULL);

if(PngID)
    GdiplusHelper::LoadImageFromResource(m_bkImage, PngID, _T("PNG"));
if(HoverPngID)
    GdiplusHelper::LoadImageFromResource(m_hoverImage, HoverPngID, _T("PNG"));

m_Width = m_bkImage.GetWidth();
m_Height = m_bkImage.GetHeight();

BOOL ret = CWnd::Create(lpszClassName, NULL, WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_VISIBLE, CRect(x, y, x + m_Width, y + m_Height), pParentWnd, nID);
ADD_EX_STYLE(GetSafeHwnd(), WS_EX_LAYERED);
```

Draw Code:

```cpp
BLENDFUNCTION pb_ = { 0 };
pb_.AlphaFormat = AC_SRC_ALPHA;
pb_.BlendOp = AC_SRC_OVER;
pb_.BlendFlags = 0;
pb_.SourceConstantAlpha = 255;

HDC dc = ::GetDC(GetSafeHwnd());
HDC mem_dc_ = CreateCompatibleDC(dc);
HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(dc, m_Width, m_Height);
CPoint  pt_(0, 0);
CSize   size_(m_Width, m_Height);
::SelectObject(mem_dc_, hBitmap);
if (!m_bkImage.IsNull())
    m_bkImage.Draw(mem_dc_, 0, 0, m_Width, m_Height);
if (m_isHover)
{
    if (!m_hoverImage.IsNull())
        m_hoverImage.Draw(mem_dc_, 0, 0, m_Width, m_Height);
}

if (!::UpdateLayeredWindow(GetSafeHwnd(), dc, nullptr, &size_, mem_dc_, &pt_, 0, &pb_, ULW_ALPHA))
{
    LOGE("UpdateLayeredWindow err:" << (int)GetLastError() );
    //BitBlt(dc, 0, 0, m_Width, m_Height, mem_dc_, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    goto cleanup;
}
cleanup:
if(mem_dc_)
    DeleteDC(mem_dc_);
if(hBitmap)
    DeleteObject(hBitmap);
if(dc)
    DeleteDC(dc);
```

In Win10, it shows normal:

[image: alpha png]

But in Win7, I get `GetLastError()=87`:

[image: seem control bg]

The problem is the function `UpdateLayeredWindow()` does not work in Win7, but I don't know why, I don't think I use the wrong parameters.

Does anyone know the reason why this is happening?

Comment: Error 87 means "The parameter is incorrect.". [System Error Codes (0-499) (WinError.h) - Win32 apps | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-)

Comment: The difference may be that `WS_EX_LAYERED` is supported only for top-level windows before Windows 8. [UpdateLayeredWindow function (winuser.h) - Win32 apps | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-updatelayeredwindow)

Comment: yes, WS_EX_LAYERED need top-level window before win8 .but in my code, i create a window use WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_VISIBLE  ,  and parent class is CWnd .. i really don't know why.....

Comment: @zero you are creating your window with a parent window specified: `CWnd::Create(..., pParentWnd, ...);` That makes it a child window if `pParentWnd` is not NULL. And like MikeCAT said, a child window can't use `WS_EX_LAYERED` in Win7.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau  Coooooooool!  it works!  thanks a lot!

Comment: Now Code:  ```BOOL ret = CreateEx(WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW, lpszClassName, _T(""),
  WS_OVERLAPPED,
  CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
  NULL, NULL);```

Comment: Note that you are calling `GetLastError` too late, at a point where it will no longer return meaningful values. As the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror) explains: *"You should call the `GetLastError` function **immediately** when a function's return value indicates that such a call will return useful data."* There must not be **any** interleaving code, as in your case.

Comment: @IInspectable: Yes this is true. But I see, he call GetLastError already immediately after UpdateLayeredWindow!?

Comment: @tom There is **guaranteed** to be interleaving code, as there is no `operator<<` defined for a character string literal and an `int`. This would either be a conversion c'tor, or a custom `operator<<` implementation. Either one is an opportunity to have the calling thread's last error code invalidated.